# PopUp for displaying Image not Working in IE

Tags: javascript

I am using the below code for displaying image in a new window.. It works fine in chrome but no in IE..
Here is my code..

```
function enlargeimg(url) {
  var newWindow = window.open("", "", "width=600,height=750");
  newWindow.document.writeln("<html>");
  newWindow.document.writeln("<body>");
  newWindow.document.writeln("<img src='" + url +"' alt='Click to close' id='bigImage'/>");
  newWindow.document.writeln("</body></html>");
  newWindow.document.close();
}
```

This how image displayed in IE popoup :-

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

IE doesn't like spaces or empty name in the window name,

try this,

```
var newWindow = window.open("", "win_with_image", "width=600,height=750");
```

Alternate solution:

If image is what you have to display in the popup,
you can try something like [ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open),

```
function openRequestedPopup() {
   var windowObjectReference = window.open(
       "http://www.domainname.ext/path/ImageFile.png",
       "DescriptiveWindowName",
       "resizable,scrollbars,status"
   );
}
```

Comment: actually my popup is working but image is not showing in IE

Comment: I have attached screenshot in the questions.

Comment: can you paste the source of the popup or inspect the window to find out more

Comment: actually my image url is in base64 fromat I am fetching the image from sql table..

Comment: What is the size of the image you are trying to display. Also please tell us what is the browser version you are testing on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158931/discussion-between-sandeep-sukhija-and-nithin).